# How to write gst h264 video stream to jpeg file?

Tags: python, jpeg, gstreamer

Am using gstreamer to stream my video over udp. (Am using python)

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src !  video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 !  x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !  udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I am capturing the stream in PyQt like this.

```
self.pipeline = gst.parse_launch("udpsrc port=5000 !  application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink")
```

Now instead of the auto video sink, I want to sink it in a jpeg file. How can I do this ?

Instead of autovideosink I have tried "jpegenc !filesink location=capture1.jpeg"

The above is wrong and gives an error. What is the best way to do this ?